# Embedded Jetty 9.4 works inside IDE but does not autonomously

Tags: jsp, jetty

I'm trying to run JSPs and Servlets using embedded Jetty. I have a standard Java application (not a web application) and it is packaged as a JAR (not a WAR) and I have a dedicated folder to store all web related files ("webui/"): web.xml, *.jsp, *.jspf, etc. This folder is in same folder as JAR and it is accessible from the application (proven).

My application works perfectly when I run it from inside NetBeans (ver. 8.1 and Java 8), but when I execute it from a shell window (java -jar myapp.jar) it provides following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /menu.jsp (line: 6, column: 0) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Before posting this, I've read (among many others) following posts:

- [Jetty 9 The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448594/jetty-9-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved)
  But I'm not using Glassfish
- Other posts say to place the JAR inside WEB-INF/lib. But I can not because I do not have WEB-INF folder because I do not follow a WEB app folders structure. I have it inside app ./lib/ folder (with all other jars).
- [Embedded Jetty Error The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621120/embedded-jetty-error-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot). I've used also the approach this post says and also the approach this post refers to (official Jetty example). In both cases I obtain the same error as with my code.

This is my POM

```
<!--Jetty dependencies start here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jetty Apache JSP  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my code

```
private static Server serverWeb = null;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

public static void Main( String[] args )
{
    JettyExampleStack instance = new JettyExampleStack();
                      instance.initServerWeb();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

private void initServerWeb()
{
    WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext();
                  ctx.setContextPath( "/" );

    serverWeb = new Server( 8080 );
    serverWeb.setHandler( ctx );
    serverWeb.setStopAtShutdown( true );
    serverWeb.setStopTimeout( UtilConvert.SECOND * 5 );

    try
    {
        initServlets( ctx );
        initJSPs( serverWeb, ctx );

        serverWeb.start();
    }
    catch( Exception exc )
    {
        UtilDebug.log( exc );
        stopdown();
    }
}

private void initServlets( WebAppContext ctx ) throws Exception
{
    ctx.addServlet( GetFile.class, "/getFile" );
}

private void initJSPs( Server server, WebAppContext ctx ) throws Exception
{
    ctx.setResourceBase( "webui" );
    ctx.setDescriptor( "web.xml" );

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // TAKEN FROM HERE:
    // https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    // By default, the JSP implementation will use an internal eclipse JDT compiler.
    // This will use the JDK JavaC built-in compiler.
    System.setProperty( "org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "false" );

    // Set a Servlet Temp Directory
    File fTmp = new File( System.getProperty( "java.io.tmpdir" ), "jetty-jsp-tmp" );
    if( ! UtilIO.createFolder( fTmp ) )
    {
        throw new IOException( "Can not create folder '"+ fTmp.getAbsolutePath() +"'" );
    }
    ctx.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", fTmp );

    // Set Classloader of Context to be sane (needed for JSTL)
    // JSP requires a non-System classloader, this simply wraps the
    // embedded System classloader in a way that makes it suitable
    // for JSP to use
    ClassLoader jspClassLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[0], WebServer.class.getClassLoader() );
    ctx.setClassLoader( jspClassLoader );

    // The JspServlet must be named "jsp" (per JSP spec).
    // Add JSP Servlet (must be named "jsp")
    ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder( "jsp", JspServlet.class );
                  holderJsp.setInitOrder( 0 );

    // Including the JSTL jars for the webapp.*/
    ctx.setAttribute( "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$" );

    // Enabling the Annotation based configuration
    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault( server );

    classlist.addBefore( "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                         "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration" );

    classlist.addAfter( "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
                        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
                        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration" );
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: Sorry Jetty version is 9.4.3

Comment: I have found a solution for the problem:

It is up to you to name and place the base resource folder as far as you properly set it using WebAppContext::setResourceBase(...)

Inside this base folder you can name and place the "web.xml" wherever you want as far as you set it using WebAppContext::setDescriptor(...)

But inside the base folder, you must have a "/WEB-INF/lib/" folder and inside this folder you have to place the "jstl-1.2.jar" file.